# How can I login with facebook and get user info to send my remote db from android application

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, facebook

Hi I'am new at an android development,I need to save user info on my remote db.I'm planning to use Facebook,Google for authentication.After successfully registration I need to send user email to my PHP page to save MySql db but I cannot find a safe way to do it without using SSL.Is there any other method to do it? Thank you for your answers

Comment: Basic SSL certificates are available at practically no cost at all these days – even if LetsEncrypt should not be an option available on your hosting platform yet, companies like StartSSL provide free certificates as well. / These days, you simply can not say you want to send data over the web in a “secure” way, and then rule out the HTTPS option – that doesn’t make any sense. You want secure, you want HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea from this example I found.

### Adding facebook login to your android application

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

Comment: essential content of the answer should be here